# Inspiration to get rid of MDI UI

Tags: .net, winforms, mdi

Microsoft seems to want us to stop using the MDI, but if more people are like me they're stuck on how things used to be. Software like Word and Excel is simple to create without MDI, but I have trouble thinking out good UI without MDI.

Is there a place where I, and others like me, can see examples on how to make great WinForms UI without using MDI. It's not my intent to start a debate on MDI pros and cons, I just wish for good examples as inspiration.

**Edit:** I decided to accept an answer that wasn't really related to the question as it ended up giving me good ideas on how to proceed. It may not be the general answer to the question, but it did help me. Further suggestions is always welcomed as well... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you stated WinForm, but [Billy Hollis](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=115) made a great UI in WPF that allow you to manage multiple document and windows (including dialog) while not being a MDI in term of embedded form.

Comment: +1 I really found this video inspiring. First a good show-off then going behind the scenes. Love it...

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on what you want to show in your (ex-) MDI Forms.

- Tabbed Forms (IE, Firefox etc)
- Tabbed with tools (Visual Studio)
- Sidebar + Collapsing panels (Outlook)
- TreeView navigation (Explorer)

And you can make various combinations of the above.

Just a Tech Tip, in case you have trouble deciding: Put your content on UserControls, derived form a common baseclass or interface. Use specialized Tabpages and/or floating Windows to host those controls. This makes it very easy to switch, or even let the user decide through drag&dock.

Comment: It should be noted that all examples with tabs can be MDI as wel (a good example of that today is Opera which still has opt-in MDI).

Answer (score 0):

If you're document-oriented, tabbed- and pane-driven design seems to be the current major paradigm.

If it's a business-style forms-driven app, tabbed- or pane-driven design can work, but may not be the ideal solution. For those, I'm finding more and more that web-style navigation paradigms work best.

For inspiration, check out software on other operating systems, as well as the latest round of all the Microsoft software -- everything from Media Player through the Office 2010 Suite and VS2010. Consider some of the following resources as well:

- [User Interface Inspiration set on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jasonrobb/sets/72157606470313238/)
- [GUIdebook Gallery (GUIs throughout history)](http://www.guidebookgallery.org/)
- [AskTog](http://www.asktog.com/)
- [**ALL** of Alan Cooper's books](http://www.cooper.com/insights/books/)

Ultimately, UI inspiration can strike from just about anywhere. Any piece of software -- even unrelated -- may have a UI idea that can be adapted to your needs. Even non-software; remember that a lot of the UI paradigms we take for granted now originated in the physical world. Keep your eyes and mind open all the time.

Answer (score -1):

> I just wish for good examples as
>   inspiration.

Check other OSes.  MDI is (mostly) a windows-only kludge.